# How do I convert a.b.c.d into something like this {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d':}}}} in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have written the logic around how to do this and output it, but I am unable to code this structure in a loop/recursive style.

```
string = "a.b.c.d"
parent = {}
keys = string.split(".")

parent[keys[0]] = dict()
parent[keys[0]][keys[1]] = dict()
parent[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = dict()
```

The below part of the logic needs to be coded:

```
parent[keys[0]] = dict()
parent[keys[0]][keys[1]] = dict()
parent[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = dict()

and so on.....
```

Comment: desired output from the title `{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d':}}}}` will yield SyntaxError, because key `d` has no associated value. Provide info on desired output in the question, not just in the title

Comment: There are definitely a few duplicates for this one. Search for "python dict dot" to see which one suits you best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `split('.', 1)` to successively break off the first part from the rest and pass it into your recursive call:

```
def dictify(s):
  if '.' not in s:
    return s
  key, rest = s.split('.', 1)
  return {key: dictify(rest)}
```

Testing it out:

```
>>> dictify('a.b.c.d')
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}
```

If you want the last level to have an empty dict as well, instead of just being the value, you can change `return s` in the first part to `return {s: {}}`

Answer (score 0):

A non recursive solution:

```py
s = "a.b.c.d"
root = None
parent = None
keys = s.split(".")

for key in keys:
    if (parent is None):
        root = {}
        parent = root
    d = {}
    parent[key] = d
    parent = d

print (root)
```

Output:

```py
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}}}}}
```